# failed to join domain with automated powershell script -- "unable to update password"

Tags: ansible, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to add a host to the domain with a Powershell script. The script fails with the error below when it's called via CloudFormation or Ansible. It's succeed when I run it manually on the host.

I suspect I'm doing something wrong with users (I run as admin manually) so I've tried to force it to run as admin all the time. Unfortunately that didn't work either.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Error:

```
> [DEBUG] Command 4-add-to-domain output: Add-Computer : Computer
> 'WIN-xxxxx' failed to join domain 
> 
> 'aws.cloud.bp.com' from its current workgroup 'WORKGROUP' with
> following error 
> 
> message: Unable to update the password. The value provided as the
> current 
> 
> password is incorrect.
> 
> At line:1 char:1
> 
> + Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential -OUPath $ouPath 
> 
> -Restar ...
> 
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 
> ~~~
> 
>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (WIN-K9DU7TO9331:String) [Add- 
> 
>    Computer], InvalidOperationException
> 
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToJoinDomainFromWorkgroup,Microsoft.PowerShe 
> 
>    ll.Commands.AddComputerCommand
```

PS1:

```
if ((gwmi win32_computersystem).partofdomain -eq $true)
{ 
    write-host "already in domain" 
}
else
{
    $domain = $domainname
    $password = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
    $username = $uid
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
    $ouPath = $oupath
    $cmd = 'Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential -OUPath $ouPath -Restart'
    $runas = [Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()

    if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
    {   
        $log = "not running as admin"
        $log | out-file -Filepath $logger -append
    } else {
        $log = "running as admin, about to run $cmd"
        $log | out-file -Filepath $logger -append
        Invoke-Expression -Command $cmd

    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I thought: when the script's running via the automation tool (either CloudFormation or Ansible) it was running as local admin. However, manually it's running as domain\admin. therefore what I needed to do is call it with username $username = "mydomain\my-domain-user" rather than simply "my-domain-user".
Hope this will help for people hitting the same problem...

Answer (score 5):

Taken from: http://www.gi-architects.co.uk/2017/01/powershell-add-computer-error-when-executed-remotely/

The root of the problem is (given that your password is correct) when running things interactively the domain is pre-appended and as such you only need to provide the user. But in a non-interactive environment, the domain is not known as such it’s a very simple fix, make sure you either include the short domain names like “contoso\DMAdmin” or the full FQDN “DMAdmin@contoso.com.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the password without the ConvertTo-SecureString? Just to test it? I had some issues with that when I was trying to remotely change local admin passwords on my domain. From what I could gather, when you convert it to a secure string and then assign it as a variable, the actual password seems to get lost. Now, I'm a real newbie with powershell, but I could only get ConvertTo-SecureString to work when it was called directly, not as a variable though.

I'm not sure why it wold work when you run it manually, but that's what I would try first to try and isolate the issue. If I'm way off feel free to correct me.

Comment: yes thanks, I've tried that too though the script just hangs, presumably waiting for input. Are you familiar with any way to force it to continue?

Comment: oh, I just noticed that you have $password set to itself.

"$password = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force"

maybe that's the problem to begin with?

Comment: nah, that's fine. The script works when running manually. I think I may need to look into using Keys. Need more research on the subject though...

Comment: oh ok, hopefully someone else can chime in then.